# Advantage of Proxies when Lazy Loading is disabled

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

WHen we disable Lazy Loading at the DbContext level, is there any advantage of still using Proxies?

Unless we disable Proxies explicitly (using: Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false), they still get created.

Also, if I understand it right, unless ALL properties are marked as virtual, we actually don't get Change Tracking proxies.

So, what are the pros?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use lazy loading and dynamic change tracking there is no advantage of dynamic proxies and you can turn them off globally.

Comment: So, does that also mean that a POCO class without ALL properties virtual and Lazy Loading turned off does not get any benefit out of a the proxy which is still created by Entity Framework?